# Can I iterate through table using JQuery and collect values in three arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I iterate  through table with id="tbl" using JQuery  with three columns and collect this value in three javascript arrays ?

Comment: [This way ?](http://jsfiddle.net/4tUww/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/SpE7F/

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function(){
    var trArray = []
    $('#tbl tr').each(function(){
            var tdArray = []
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                tdArray.push($(this).text())
            })
            trArray.push(tdArray)     
    })
    //console.log(trArray)
    for(row = 0; row < trArray.length; row++){
        for(cell = 0; cell < trArray[row].length; cell++){
            alert('row: '+row+', cell: '+cell+' value: '+trArray[row][cell])   
        }
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<table id="tbl" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>        
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to find the Nth element in a 'tr'
so `$("#tbl td").eq(2)` would get you the 3rd 'td'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
firstCols = new Array();
secondCols = new Array();
thirdCols = new Array();

$(function() {
    $("#tbl tr").each(function(i) {
        var firstChild = $(this).children().first();
        firstCols[i] = firstChild.text();
        secondCols[i] = firstChild.next().text();
        thirdCols[i] = firstChild.next().next().text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
// Column-arrays
var col1 = new Array();
var col2 = new Array();
var col3 = new Array();

// Cache table
var table = $('#tbl');

// Iteratate over rows
var rows = table.find('tr');
rows.each(function() {
   // Iterate over columns
   var columns = this.children('td');
   // Save column-values in separate arrays
   col1.push(columns[0].html());
   col2.push(columns[1].html());
   col3.push(columns[2].html());
});
```

Comment: This will probably not work, as the `tr` elements are not children of the `table` but of the `tbody` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the columns and organize it via the index. This isn't a semantic table, but if you add the header/body just make sure to change the selector appropriately as well.

```
var arr = [];
$('#tbl td').each(function(){
    var colId = $(this).index();
    var rowId = $(this).parent().index();
    if (arr[colId] == undefined) {
        arr[colId] = [];
    }
    arr[colId][rowId] = $(this).html();
});
console.log(arr);
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MfxA9/

Here's the HTML

```
<table id='tbl'>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1 : Row 1</td>
        <td>Col 2 : Row 1</td>
        <td>Col 3 : Row 1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Col 1 : Row 2</td>
        <td>Col 2 : Row 2</td>
        <td>Col 3 : Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1 : Row 3</td>
        <td>Col 2 : Row 3</td>
        <td>Col 3 : Row 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Col 1 : Row 4</td>
        <td>Col 2 : Row 4</td>
        <td>Col 3 : Row 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```